# Bad image Quality when using own Camera Activity

Tags: android, image, camera, android-camera, camera-calibration

We are using an LG Optimus speed and are trying to obtain an image from the camera with our own activity. The Code we are using to do so is:

```
GetImage(new PictureCallback(){
  @Override
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    camera.startPreview();
    bmp = BitmapConversion.convertBmp(data));
  }
});

...

public static void GetImage(final PictureCallback jpgCallback) {
    GetCamera().autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            if(success)
                GetCamera().takePicture(null, null, jpgCallback);
            else
                GetImage(jpgCallback);
        }       
    });         
}
```

The images have a considerable worse quality than the images obatained with the native android camera app. Here are 2 example pictures, both taken with a resolution of 640x480 an magnified. As you can see the left picture taken with the native app looks "cleaner" than the right taken with our own application.

[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you accidentally reversed the images? The image currently on the right is far less pixelated than the one on the left.  Perhaps you meant that the native app took the one on the right and yours took the one on the left?

Comment: Those two images look like they have about the same original resolution; you've just scaled them up using two different resampling algorithms! Try taking the 640×480 images and *use the same program to magnify both*.

Comment: It would appear to me that you are blowing up the thumbnail. I ran into this problem using the Camera API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't know what the native app is doing  in terms of configuring the camera before taking the image and post-processing after taking the image.

There are many settings available on the camera which are well documented and should be investigated.

You should also  be aware that vastly different results exist on using the same method but with the slightest variation in light and focus.

Try looking into the autofocus settings and perhaps do something on autofocus callback.

When comparing the two methods make sure your camera is balanced on something rather than handheld and ensure that the distance and light levels are identical.

Comment: Our images always have this noise in them, independent of the conditions under which they were taken. Additionally we used the same program on a Samsung mobile and the images obtained there were much clearer.

Comment: Perhaps the LG has an inferior camera and is using some kind of software compensation in their native camera app.  There must be some magic sauce in it somewhere.  What about Samsung native vs your app on Samsung?

Comment: Yes we used autofocus. It turns out that if we set the Options in the BitmapFactory explicitly to inDither = false the strange Pattern in the image disapears. I don't know why it did not have the same effect on the Samsung device but anyhow, the pattern is gone now ;)